# Can't use a php script

Tags: php, html, forms

So, I'm trying to use a .php script to print data from a form, but everytime i try to call that script all i get is a page with the php code on it, and i can't figure out why. I don't have any errors in the code. Or at least it won't show me that i have any.
Here is the code:

```
<DOCTYPE html>

<body>
<?php


if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 

{
    $firstName=$_POST['first'];
    
    $lastName=$_POST['last'];
    echo "Last Name: " .$lastName .$firstName . " <br />";
    $password=$_POST['pw'];
    echo "Password: " .$password . " <br />";
    $status =$_POST['status'];
    echo "Status: " .$status . "<br />";
    $waitList = $_POST['waitlist'];
    echo "Wait List: " .$waitList . "<br />";
}

?>

</body>
```

This is the main page code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 

<body>

<form name="register" action="process.php  " method="post" autocomplete="off" >
<p>First Name: <input type= "text" name="first" /></p>
<p>Last Name: <input type= "text" name="last" /></p>
<p>Pasword: <input type="password" name="pw"/></p>
<p>Status: 
    <input type="radio" name="status" value="enrolled" checked>Endrolled
    <input type="radio" name="status" value="notEnrolled">Not Enrolled </p>
<p><input type="checkbox" name="waitlist" value="true" checked="checked">Add me to the waiting list</p>
<p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign in" /> </p>
</form> 
</body>
```

[image]

I really need some help with this, i am completly lost here..

Comment: Does your file have a .php extension?

Comment: Check that your PHP server is running. Also check that your server is configured to treat .php files (not files with  other extensions) as PHP scripts.

Comment: Yes, the file is process.php

Comment: Are you running a server? May help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-instead-code-shows-on-the-page

Comment: Also make sure you are cleansing your $_POST data with sanitation filters!

Comment: not running a server, i'm kinda new at this, and nobody said anything about a server in every tutorial i've seen, i guess they assume i would know that, but i'm working on it now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have directly opened the file in the browser (you can see it from the photo), download a program like XAMPP to start a local server and view the content

Comment: Although i needed some help with how it works, this was helpful, so thanks.

Comment: Go [here](https://www.apachefriends.org/it/index.html) download XAMPP and install, next step go to localhost folder (ex: `C:\xampp\htdocs`) then put your file into this folder. Now open XAMPP control panel start apache server and mysql(if you need) then open browser and put into url bar `localhost/NameOfFile.php` and have you finish

Answer (score 0):

You can not access the file directly.
PHP code needs to be compiled.
If you are using Windows WAMP device, you will run the server and log in via http
Unlike PHP, running HTML is directly on the browser so you see your HTML "code"

see:
https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-set-up-your-own-wampserver/

Answer (score 0):

you should install xammp server[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6sG53.png)